# Fixing SQL Parameterization

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

I'm having some trouble updating some of my SQL queries to use parameters as opposed to string concatenation. Nothing super hard, I'm just trying to figure out what I'm missing or am doing wrong.

The end query should look like

```
SELECT [DeviceSeq], [DeviceName], [SerialNumber], [Premise], [InsertDate], [VersionNumber], [LastUpdateDate], [IsDeleted] FROM [ITAM].[dbo].[AllDevices] WHERE DeviceName LIKE '%InputFilter%' OR SerialNumber = 'InputFilter'
```

Previously I was doing it like so, and it returns the results I expect.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT [DeviceSeq], [DeviceName], [SerialNumber], [Premise], [InsertDate], [VersionNumber], [LastUpdateDate], [IsDeleted] FROM [ITAM].[dbo].[AllDevices] WHERE DeviceName LIKE '%@" + filter + "%' OR SerialNumber = '" + filter + "'";
```

But what I'm trying to do is this. However, every time that I try to do it this way (parameterized) it returns 0 results or errors out depending on how I try and format it.

```
List<dynamic> hosts = new List<dynamic>();
using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [DeviceSeq], [DeviceName], [SerialNumber], [Premise], [InsertDate], [VersionNumber], [LastUpdateDate], [IsDeleted] FROM [ITAM].[dbo].[AllDevices] WHERE DeviceName LIKE '%@filter%' OR SerialNumber = '@filter'";

    var param = new SqlParameter("filter", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Value = filter;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);


    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dynamic h = new ITAMHost()
            {
                DeviceSeq = reader[0].ToString(),
                DeviceName = reader[1].ToString(),
                SerialNumber = reader[2].ToString(),
                Premise = reader[3].ToString(),
                InsertDate = reader[4].ToString(),
                VersionNumber = reader[5].ToString(),
                LastUpdateDate = reader[6].ToString(),
                IsDeleted = reader[7].ToString(),
            };
            hosts.Add(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters are not inline text replacements. You're comparing `DeviceName` to values that contain the actual text "@filter" (and `SerialNumber` equal to "@filter"), not what the `@filter` parameter contains. You would have to use `DeviceName LIKE @filter` and include the wildcards in the paramter value, although that has the potential to allow for a denial of service attack in which the input is a very complex pattern that takes the engine a very long time to execute. You would then have to disallow wildcard characters in the input or escape them.

Comment: @madreflection : Thank you! I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try changing your code like this :

```
List<dynamic> hosts = new List<dynamic>();
using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [DeviceSeq], [DeviceName], [SerialNumber], [Premise], [InsertDate], [VersionNumber], [LastUpdateDate], [IsDeleted] FROM [ITAM].[dbo].[AllDevices] WHERE DeviceName LIKE @filter OR SerialNumber = @filter";

    var param = new SqlParameter("filter", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Value = "%YOUR_FILTER_VALUE%";
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dynamic h = new ITAMHost()
            {
                DeviceSeq = reader[0].ToString(),
                DeviceName = reader[1].ToString(),
                SerialNumber = reader[2].ToString(),
                Premise = reader[3].ToString(),
                InsertDate = reader[4].ToString(),
                VersionNumber = reader[5].ToString(),
                LastUpdateDate = reader[6].ToString(),
                IsDeleted = reader[7].ToString(),
            };
            hosts.Add(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Between this and @madreflection 's answers, I understand now.

Comment: Be sure to take into consideration escaping of wildcards... LIKE uses underscore for a single character in addition to percent for zero or more characters, so replace `_` with `[_]` and `%` with `[%]` before wrapping in `%` to match those characters instead of treating them as wildcards.

Comment: That doesn't work for the equality check for `SerialNumber` as it now has the % wildcard values.  Instead the wildcards can be added in the query like this `Where DeviceName LIKE '%' + @filter + '%' OR SerialNumber = @filter`.  Or this would require two parameters if you want to add the wildcards into the parameter.